# Using DisplayMemberPath to select an Image when binding a ListBox to an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm binding a `ListBox` to an `ObservableCollection` of items which have an `Image` property, which returns an `Image`. However, instead of getting a list of images, I get this:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ObservableCollectionDirectoryListBox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <DockPanel>

        <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                 Name="listBox"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource infos}}"
                 DisplayMemberPath="Image"/>

    </DockPanel>

</Window>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace ObservableCollectionDirectoryListBox
{
    public class ImageFileInfo : FileSystemInfo
    {
        public Image Image
        {
            get
            {
                var image = new Image() { Width = 100 };

                var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage.BeginInit();
                bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(this.FullName);
                bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 100;
                bitmapImage.EndInit();

                image.Source = bitmapImage;

                return image;
            }
        }

        public ImageFileInfo(string path)
            : base()
        {
            FullPath = path;
        }

        public override void Delete()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool Exists
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override string Name
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            var infos = new ObservableCollection<ImageFileInfo>();

            Resources.Add("infos", infos);

            InitializeComponent();

            new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\dharmatech\Pictures\From dharmatech\Camera roll")
            .GetFiles("*.jpg")
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(file => infos.Add(new ImageFileInfo(file.FullName)));

            var fileSystemWatcher =
                new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Users\dharmatech\Pictures\From dharmatech\Camera roll") 
                { EnableRaisingEvents = true };

            var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;

            fileSystemWatcher.Created += (s, e) =>
                context.Post(val =>
                {
                    if ((File.GetAttributes(e.FullPath) & FileAttributes.Normal) ==
                        FileAttributes.Normal)
                        infos.Add(new ImageFileInfo(e.Name));
                }, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't really have a collection of `Images` which is a control and does not belong there, instead it should be a collection of `ImageSource`, which then in a `DataTemplate` (`ListBox.ItemTemplate`) can be bound to the `Source` of an `Image`.

Comment: Hi H.B. I've been looking through the book WPF 4 Unleashed. He suggests something along the lines of what you describe above. I was just trying a different approach for experimentation. Even if it isn't a best practice, I'd like to understand why the images aren't showing up.

Comment: @dharmatech: Presumably the `ListBox` creates a `TextBox` and binds the `Text` to the specified `DisplayMemberPath`, which causes `ToString` to be invoked on the `Image` which returns the type name. I have no idea why they don't just bind the `Content` of a `ContentPresenter` instead. You could test this hypothesis by examining the `VisualTree` using the `VisualTreeHelper` (or some external tool like Snoop).

Comment: Here's a quote from chapter 13 of the book "For getting the actual images to display in the ListBox, you could add an Image property to the Photo class and use that as the DisplayMemberPath. But there are more flexible ways to control the presentation of bound data—ways that don’t require changes to the source object." So basically, I was trying out his first suggestion, even though he sort of advises against it.

Comment: I think that the DisplayMemberPath is only meant to apply to string properties, for non-strings ToString() is used as @H.B. says. It's a shame that the MSDN documentation is ambiguous : "If DisplayMemberPath is not specified and there is no DataTemplate, then the ListBox displays a string representation of each object in the underlying collection"

Comment: Just to add, given the above. It seems to me that WPF 4 unleashed is wrong - I can't seem to find any online errata though.

Comment: @AndrewJones: That bit is not ambiguous but it rather just does not make any claim about how the path itself is used. (The string representation mentioned would be that of the owning class, `ImageFileInfo`)

Comment: I added an answer describing how I solved the problem. Thanks again H.B.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem using a `DataTemplate`. Here's the Xaml code for the `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Top"
         Name="listBox"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource infos}}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=FullName}" Height="35"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```